# Wordpress custom rest api routes not showing up, how to get debugging info

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

Wordpress isn't throwing any errors, even in debug mode, but none of my custom routes are showing up.  I have the following method that loads in the data.

I have the following `rest_api_init` hook inside a class constructor.

`add_action( 'rest_api_init', [$this, 'addApiRoutes'] );`

That calls this method.

```
    public function addApiRoutes() {

        register_rest_route( $this->namespace, '/logout', [
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => [ $this, 'logout' ],
        ] );
        return $this;
    }

    public function logout() {
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect('/');
        exit;
    }
```

If I do a `die(__LINE__ . __FILE__)`, I can see that the method (addApiRoutes) is being invoked.  But when I check the route, I get a 404.  When I visit the `wp-json` url, the route doesn't show up either, nor the namespace.

How do you debug this?  I also checked the `deprecated calls` section of Wordpress, but no errors are showing up there either.

Comment: Have you tried returning something in your callback function? Btw what are you trying to do with that custom endpoint? You better send a post request instead of get request if you don't want to return anything...

Comment: Which callback?  The `logout` one is never called.  The addApiRoutes one is called, `die` shows it dying at the line and file when I added it.


It's a GET request because they should hit `/logout` and it should log them out and redirect them to the home page to log back in again or whatever else they want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's the answer.  I was using `/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/{customRoute}` to do the lookup, which gave me a route not found each time.  The actual route is `/index.php/wp-json/{customRoutes}`.  The `wp/v2` stuff is apparently only for internal stuff Wordpress uses, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's not true. `/wp-json/wp/v2` is the correct base endpoint to use at present day.